# Is there a way to implement a client-endpoint on Bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I need to use client-app-support and client-endpoint tags inside an endpoints file but I keep getting this error message: "Experimental feature, not available for external use".

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: As dogethis mentioned, please reach out to the Support team for help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the error, that feature is not available for external use.

If you think this a mistake, please file a support ticket through the IDE.